# Between MOnths In oracle when date is greater than 10 of every month

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

My question is basically i want to increment months by one USING **MONTHS_BETWEEN** IN ORACLE 
when date is greater than 10 of every month my query is :

```
CASE
    when 
        TRUNC( months_between(TO_DATE(K.RECORD_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY'),TO_DATE(K.DUE_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY')) ) <= 0 then 0
    when
       --to_number(to_char(K.RECORD_DATE,'dd')) >10
       TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR( TO_DATE(k.RECORD_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY'),'DD')) > 10 

        then     
        TRUNC( months_between(K.RECORD_DATE,K.DUE_DATE) )+1
        else
            TRUNC( months_between(K.RECORD_DATE,K.DUE_DATE) )
    end as mths
FROM 
TBL_PAYMENT_DTL K
```

Comment: Not clear what you want to achieve - do you want to add one to the difference between two dates by one or do you want to add one month to existing date ? What do you expect to see as a result ? Could you please give some example ?

Comment: @DmitryNikiforov on second clause or when statement i want to icrement mths by one when date is greater than 10 .. but it is not working..please suggest,,

Comment: What is data type of RECORD_DATE and DUE_DATE columns ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `to_date()` in `months_between()`.

```
select 
CASE
    when 
        TRUNC( months_between(TO_DATE(K.RECORD_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY'),TO_DATE(K.DUE_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY')) ) <= 0 then 0
    when
       --to_number(to_char(K.RECORD_DATE,'dd')) >10
       TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR( TO_DATE(k.RECORD_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY'),'DD')) > 10 

        then     
        TRUNC( months_between(TO_DATE(k.RECORD_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY'),TO_DATE(k.DUE_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY')) )+1
        else
            TRUNC( months_between(TO_DATE(k.RECORD_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY'),TO_DATE(k.DUE_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY')) )
    end as mths
FROM 
TBL_PAYMENT_DTL K
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the EXTRACT function to get the day part of the date, as below:

```
SELECT
CASE
    when 
        extract(day from K.RECORD_DATE) > 10 then K.RECORD_DATE
    else
       add_months(K.RECORD_DATE, 1) 
    end as mths
from 
TBL_PAYMENT_DTL K
```